# hydrated_bloc: The parameter 'storageDirectory' is required

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, pubspec

I updated hydrated_bloc from 6.1.0 to the latest 7.0.1 and I got a warning in:

```
HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(); The parameter 'storageDirectory' is required.
```

When I changed to what the new documentation suggested

```
HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
storageDirectory: await getTemporaryDirectory(),); The function 'getTemporaryDirectory' isn't defined.
```

I also tried:

```
HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(storageDirectory: await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),); The function 'getApplicationDocumentsDirectory' isn't defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `getTemporaryDirectory` and `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` are part of the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package, so, you have to import it in your main.dart file

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need path [Provider Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider), you might also experience this error "StorageNotFound (Storage was accessed before it was initialized), or The setter 'storage' isn't defined for the type 'HydratedBloc' in Android Studio
[image: StorageNotFound (Storage was accessed before it was initialized]
instead define it as below: `

```
 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
  );
  HydratedBlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () => runApp(MyApp(
      appRouter: AppRouter(),
      connectivity: Connectivity(),
    )),
    storage: storage,
  );
}
```

`
You can get [the full code here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/packages/hydrated_bloc/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: (How to Use the Hydrated bloc Package Tested for 8.0.0  in dart  Flutter Mobile  Application, fork it on GitHub)[https://github.com/TrophyDevelopersUganda/testing_bloc/blob/Hydrated-State-mgt-mobile-app-flutter/lib/main.dart]